# Mongoose Virtual Populate, what is mongoose#trustedSymbol?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This are my schemas:

user.js

```
'use strict'

const { models, model, Schema } = require('mongoose')

const schema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
        discriminatorKey: 'type',
    }
)

schema.virtual('posts', {
    ref: 'Post',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'user',
})

module.exports = models.User|| model('User', schema)
```

post.js

```
'use strict'

const { models, model, Schema } = require('mongoose')


const schema = new Schema(
    {
        text: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
            required: true,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
        discriminatorKey: 'type',
    }
)

module.exports = models.Post|| model('Post', schema)
```

And the Query:

```
const user = await UserModel.findById(req.params.id).populate('posts')
```

I don't know what i doing wrong, but populate is not returning anything

I turn on my mongoose debug flag to check what is the query for virtual populate and see that on my terminal:

```
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: new ObjectId("6182fce8c339b6f51c933eee") }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: posts.find({ user: { '$in': [ new ObjectId("6182fce8c339b6f51c933eee") ], [Symbol(mongoose#trustedSymbol)]: true }}, { skip: 0, limit: 10, perDocumentLimit: undefined, projection: {} })
```

I do the query manually again

```
const posts = await PostModel.find({credential: { $in: [Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)]}})
```

and return data :/

and terminal print:

```
Mongoose: posts.find({ user: { '$in': [ new ObjectId("6182fce8c339b6f51c933eee") ] } }, { projection: {} })
```

Answer (score 0):

As to answer the question what "**mongoose#trustedSymbol**" means, I refer to these articles for more depth on sanitize input against query selector injections:

[Defending Against Query Selector Injection Attacks](https://thecodebarbarian.com/2014/09/04/defending-against-query-selector-injection-attacks.html)

[What's New in Mongoose 6: The 'sanitizeFilter' Option](https://thecodebarbarian.com/whats-new-in-mongoose-6-sanitizefilter.html)

In short, the `mongoose.trusted()` function can be used to accomplish trust for a symbol starting with '$' in a query, which resolves to `[Symbol(mongoose#trustedSymbol)]: true`